# How to attach text to an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Sooo I am making a card game for a jam and I am making a system where the card level and cost go up each time you deploy it. For that i cant use the card as a single sprite, instead i will use one sprite (with the name and description on it) and the level and cost go separate.
The problem I'm facing is if I move the card on game the cost and level of that card will remain on the same spot, how can I make it move along?

Comment: Are you saying that the texts don't move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Canvas `Render Mode` to World Space:

[image]